# zebra printing on ICS, intents and license

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

We are developing a new App for internal use that will rely on a RW420 Zebra printer for POS printing. I have been looking for documentation on the issue and I still have three questions I have not been able to resolve:

a) Pricing: Is there any amount to pay for using the SDK on a commercial app?. We are developing it on behalf of our final client. I have been able to download the SDK from their page at no cost but still have concerns over it.

b) ICS support: It seems the SDK has not been evolved since 2.1/2.2 Android releases. Will this be an issue?. Currently it is possible to use the Zebra App under ICS, but don't want to go deeper on programming just to see all the efforts have been futile.

c) Do I really need the SDK or is it possible to use an intent (found nothing about it)?

If you have another similar printer suggestion to substitute the Zebra, I will be delighted to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. [1] <strike>AFAIK no, but contact them if you want to be super sure.</strike>
2. No, ICS should be completely backwards-compatible with well programmed Android 2.1/2.2 applications and libraries.
3. In order for an Intent to work, the user would already have to have some ZebraLink Android application installed on their device in order for that to process the intent. There is an app "Zebra Utilities" but it does not have an Intent you can use to print. [2] <strike>AFAIK there is no such application, so no.</strike>

Sources: [1] & [2] see the comments by OTisler (Zebra employee).

Comment: no cost for the sdk. There is an app, "Zebra Utilities" put we did not create/publish an activity to hook into for printing.

Comment: Cheers for the info -- do you work for Zebra out of interest?

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to know so I can make the language of my answer more certain should anyone come looking for the same info in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses on this !!